# How to change data type and format in libre calc?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Libre office - Version: 6.4.7.2

My Libre office Calc is set to recognize numbers that are this format:

“10,12”

My problem is that my data is like this:

“10.12”

Libre thinks that it is a text when I enter.

How I can convert it into the number?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry if this is supposed to be in the comment instead of answer, but I don't have enough reputation to do so...

Assuming you normally use comma as your decimal separator, then the solution you need is here (The article is written for Excel, but it works in Calc too.
):
[Convert European Number to US (or vice versa)](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3785-excel-convert-european-number-to-us.html)

The short answer is to use the formula:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(A2,".",",")
```

This assumes your data is in A2. Modify accordingly.

IF, however, you ALWAYS want to use period for your decimal separator, then you need to check your settings.

- Tools --> Options
- Language Settings -> Languages
- Decimal separator key: check Same as locale setting (assuming your locale is using . as decimal separator).

Comment: Don't feel bad, this is an actual answer.